# Array to string conversion on creating chained combobox with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, drop-down-menu, combobox

i'm trying to create a chained combobox (2 combobox) with codeigniter, the result is ok but when i inspect it with dev tools on chrome show:

> **array to string conversion**

and i don't know how to solve it.

Here's my code:

**Controller**:

```
public function create() 
{
  $this->data['get_all_data'] = $this->Category_model->getkat(); 
  $this->load->view('back/tool/tool_add', $this->data);
}


function get_subkat()
{
  $id_kat     = $this->input->post('id_kat');
  $datasubkat = $this->Category_model->getdatasubkat($id_kat);

  $this->data .= "<option value=''>-- CHOOSE --</option>";
  foreach($datasubkat as $data_subkat)
  {
    $this->data .= "<option value='$data_subkat[id_subkat]'>$data_subkat[nama_subkat]</option>";
  }
  echo $this->data;
}
```

**Model**:

```
function getkat() 
{
  $result = $this->db->get($this->table);
  if($result->num_rows() > 0)
  {
    return $result->result_array();
  }
  else
  {return array();}
}

function getdatasubkat($id_kat)
{
  $this->db->where('id_kat', $id_kat);
  $result = $this->db->get('subkategori');
  if($result->num_rows() > 0)
  {
    return $result->result_array();
  }
  else
  {return array();}
}
```

**View**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#kat").change(function(){
    var id_kat = $("#kat").val();
    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'POST', 
        url: "<?php echo base_url('admin/tool/get_subkat'); ?>", 
        data:"id_kat="+id_kat, 
        success: function(data) {
          $("#subkat").html(data);
        }
    });
  });
});
</script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6"><b>Category</b>
    <select name="kat" id="kat" class="form-control">
      <option value="">-- CHOOSE --</option>
      <?php 
        foreach($get_all_data as $category){
        echo "<option value=".$category['id_kat'].">".$category['nama_kat']."</option>";
        } 
      ?>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6"><b>Sub category</b>
    <select name="subkat" id="subkat" class="form-control">
      <option value="">-- CHOOSE --</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help will be so appreciated, thank you

Comment: attach a screenie from this message of chrome

Comment: here @sintakonte https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-L7ROOaxIR24/WEqz4KoX_UI/AAAAAAAABWo/u1opXI3_A2oTa45jph6tqsGyoWZZlEHHgCLcB/s1600/ss1.png